# how to convert dplyr::summaries to dplyr::do

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-analysis, tidyr

I have the following data frame:

```
 label  target    sale
   low    5000    4000
   low   11000    9000
   low    5500    4500
   low   12000    9500
middle   20000   18000
middle   22000  190000
  high  100000   90000
  high  120000   95000
```

I need to first group my data frame by label and then calculate: mean(target - sale) only for rows where target is more than 10000, I tried following code:

```
library(dplyr)
avg_increase <- df %>% 
                  group_by(labels) %>%
                  summarise(avg_sale_increase = ifelse(target >= 10000,mean(target - sale), 0))
```

and I get the following error:

> Error: expecting a single value

As `summarise` only returns single values, should I change my code using `deployer::do` (or any other suggestion) to accomplish the task.

Comment: Have you thought about doing: `df %>% 
                  group_by(labels, target>=1000) %>%
                  summarise(avg_sale_increase = mean(target - sale))`.

This does not answer your question directly but it will provide you with 2 lines for each label: the avg sale increase for targets over 10K and the average sale increase for targets below 10K. Please also consider using relative error instead of absolute error, which is useful to compare sale increase for a wide range of targets. With relative errors, there is likely less need to filter the targets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with ifelse, which returns a vector if length equal to the input logical, so the mean is going to be calculated as many times as required.

This should work

```
avg_increase <- df %>% 
                group_by(labels) %>% 
                filter(target >= 10000) %>% 
                summarise(target = mean(target-sale))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could filter for rows>10000 bevor grouping the variable.

```
dat %>% filter(target>10000) %>% 
    group_by(label) %>% mutate(differ = mean(target-sale))
```

Comment: Apols, same time, same answer.

Comment: exactly same answer, Thank you a lot, as @NJBurgo was a little bit faster i choose it as the best answer.